# How does using synonyms at both query and index time differ from just query time?

Tags: apache, search, solr, analyzer

I'm making a new *fieldType* in my schema.xml and I wanted to know what the main differences were between using synonymGraphFilterFactory in both index and query analyzer chains instead of just the query chain. Any insight into this and also how these two chains fundamentally differ would be awesome.

Comment: There's a [decent explanation available here](https://nolanlawson.com/2012/10/31/better-synonym-handling-in-solr/).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks a lot, I'll check it out.